# As a user starts to type in an EditText can it append a file extension to the end?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, append

**Problem:** I've been trying unsuccessfully to append a file extension which follows the cursor in real-time as a user types.

**What I've tried:** I've been trying to use the `.addTextChangedListener()` which I think is correct, but having an issue trying to make the idea happen. Debugging shows is continually looping and so it gives the appearance of freezing. I looked at a couple post here on the forum but the ones suggested when I entered this post title dealt with prefixes and not suffixes.

**EditText field with highlighted area representing text to follow right of cursor:**

[image: EditText]

**One of my poor attempts to make it work:**

private void setupAddDBEditText(){

```
    mDBToAdd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().contains(".db"))
                mDBToAdd.setText(s.toString().substring(0,s.toString().length()-3));
            mDBToAdd.setText(s + ".db");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the listener when you change the text (that's why you are getting an infinite loop).

You can make a custom `TextWatcher` to handle this sort of thing (below) that removes itself as a watcher, changes the text and puts the cursor in the right place, then adds itself back.

```java
public class FileExtensionTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final String extension;
    private final EditText text;

    FileExtensionTextWatcher(EditText t, String ext) {
        extension = ext;
        text = t;
    }

    // you may want to change around the logic in here to allow for
    // odd entries or other changes - but the overall approach should
    // be similar
    private String removeAutoExtension(String s) {
        String ext = "." + extension;
        if( s.contains(ext) ) {
            int ei = s.lastIndexOf(ext);
            if( ei == 0 ) return "";
            String trailingChar = "";
            if( ei < s.length() - ext.length() ) {
                trailingChar = s.substring(ei+ext.length());
            }
            return s.substring(0,ei) + trailingChar;
        }
        else {
            return s;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable txt) {
        if( txt == null ) return;

        String currentText = txt.toString();
        String filename = removeAutoExtension(currentText);
        int initCursor = filename.length();
        String displayedText;
        if( filename.isEmpty() ) {
            displayedText = filename;
        }
        else {
            displayedText = filename + "." + extension;
        }

        text.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        txt.clear();
        txt.insert(0, displayedText);
        text.setSelection(initCursor);
        text.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this

```java
EditText e = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
e.addTextChangedListener(new FileExtensionTextWatcher(e, "db"));
```

Here is a demo GIF of how it looks.

[image: demo GIF]

There are some changes you may want to make to handle things like whether the user is allowed to enter their own extension (this form does not allow it - but you could change that with some extra logic in the custom watcher).

Comment: Wow, I appreciate this, thanks for the work and demonstration, I wasn't expecting that. I studied and stepped through it - nice! I probably won't modify it. I like the restrictiveness of it, and I will probably keep it as is and further restrict some special characters and spaces, which I have through the activity layout. - Thanks again.